# Decouple view manipulation from input source

Tags: c#, wpf

In graphics-intensive engineering software (CAD, FEM pre/post-processing) as well as in games it is quite common to decouple the continuous manipulation actions of the view from the input sources that cause these manipulations. For example, rotation of a 2D or 3D view might be accomplished by any of

- Ctrl-Key + LeftMouse-Drag
- MouseWheel Rotation
- dragging a slider control in the UI
- pushing an axis on a 3D mouse like 3DConnexion

In the settings of the application, the user might be given the freedom to reassign the manipulation "Rotate View" to one of these mouse input actions, in order to customize the behavior of the app to his liking (or probably to what he is accustomed to from other applications).

Is there an accepted way to do such decoupling in WPF or will I have to come up with my own solution for it?

I have thought about Commands, but I guess this doesn't really fit because moving the mouse is not a trigger of a command. Maybe gestures would be closest, but they seem to be more or less designed for touch input.

I think the problem is also the possible complexity: many different Key/Mouse-Button/Mouse-Axes combinations. There is even some cases where the sequence of button-presses determines the view-manipulation (namely CATIA V5).

Comment: Oliver, how about you use MVVM pattern? You can use commands and bindings to do it.

Comment: @MichelBorges: yes, that was the question: how to apply MVVM to that specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what pushing an axis on a 3d mouse means.
I'm writing a wpf game suite right now and I use MVVM with a combination of mechanisms for mousebindings.
Slider controls just drag, the thing you drag is called a thumb.
You can put pretty much anything inside anything in wpf ui and one way to make something draggable is to put it inside a thumb.
This is how you drag units around to position them when setting up a scenario.

Here's some markup from the scenario editor pieceview. You can drag these and change facing by hovering the mouse over a piece and rotating the mouse wheel. You can also ctrl+click with left or right button to change rotation angle in chunks. The viewmodel changes a double Facing property which is bound to angle on a rotatetransform for that.

```
    <UserControl.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="local:CommandLibrary.LeftClick"   Executed="LeftClick_Executed" />
        <CommandBinding Command="local:CommandLibrary.RightClick"  Executed="RightClick_Executed" />
    </UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <UserControl.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="Shift+LeftClick" 
                      Command="{Binding RotateCounterClockWiseCommand}"
                      CommandParameter="{StaticResource FortyFive}"/>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="Shift+RightClick" 
                      Command="{Binding RotateClockWiseCommand}"
                      CommandParameter="{StaticResource FortyFive}"/>
<!--  Up is away from user and Down is towards user   -->
        <MouseBinding Gesture="{local:MouseWheel Direction=Up}" 
                      Command="{Binding RotateCounterClockWiseCommand}"
                      CommandParameter="{StaticResource Five}"/>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="{local:MouseWheel Direction=Down}" 
                      Command="{Binding RotateClockWiseCommand}"
                      CommandParameter="{StaticResource Five}"/>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" 
                      Command="local:CommandLibrary.LeftClick" 
                      CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:PieceView}}}"
                      />
        <MouseBinding Gesture="RightClick" 
                      Command="local:CommandLibrary.RightClick" 
                      CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:PieceView}}}"
                      />
    </UserControl.InputBindings>
```

The reason I'm mixing ways of implementing commands is because I'm using clicking for several purposes and straight mousebinding doesn't like that so much. I would otherwise very rarely use routeduicommands.

Mouse Wheel Gesture

```
public enum MouseWheelDirection { Up, Down }

public class MouseWheelGesture : MouseGesture
{
    public MouseWheelDirection Direction { get; set; }

    public MouseWheelGesture(ModifierKeys keys, MouseWheelDirection direction)
        : base(MouseAction.WheelClick, keys)
    {
        Direction = direction;
    }

    public override bool Matches(object targetElement, InputEventArgs inputEventArgs)
    {
        var args = inputEventArgs as MouseWheelEventArgs;
        if (args == null)
            return false;
        if (!base.Matches(targetElement, inputEventArgs))
            return false;
        if (   Direction == MouseWheelDirection.Up && args.Delta > 0
            || Direction == MouseWheelDirection.Down && args.Delta < 0)
        {
            inputEventArgs.Handled = true;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}

public class MouseWheel : MarkupExtension
{
    public MouseWheelDirection Direction { get; set; }
    public ModifierKeys Keys { get; set; }

    public MouseWheel()
    {
        Keys = ModifierKeys.None;
        Direction = MouseWheelDirection.Down;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return new MouseWheelGesture(Keys, Direction);
    }
}
```

Here's one of the commands out PieceVM:

```
private RelayCommand<Double> rotateClockWiseCommand;

public RelayCommand<Double> RotateClockWiseCommand
{
    get
    {
        return rotateClockWiseCommand
        ?? (rotateClockWiseCommand = new RelayCommand<Double>(
        (increase) =>
        {
            if(Facing + increase > 359)
            {
                Facing = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                Facing += increase;
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

RelayCommand comes from MVVMLight. You add that using nuget MvvmLightLibs.

Each Piece ( on the board ) is a usercontrol with a PieceVM as it's datacontext. The actual pieces are produced by templating which associates a piecevm with a piece. It's a fairly standard viewmodel first approach.

Here's the rotation transform.

```
<UserControl.RenderTransform>
    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Facing, FallbackValue=0, TargetNullValue=0}" />
</UserControl.RenderTransform>
```

A piece is actually circular since it's root is a border:

```
<Border  CornerRadius="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
         Width="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
         Name="border"
         BorderThickness="1.5"
         >
```

Comment: How does rotating by mouse movement (maybe it was wrong to talk about "dragging") fit in this picture?

Comment: It handles the rotation of the mousewheel in a decoupled command. How does it not fit into a question asking how to handle mousewheel rotation?

Comment: No problem Andy, thanks. But as you can see the mousewheel is only one part of my question. The first item in my list specifically is about mouse movement used for rotation and why I fail to see an out-of-the-box solution scheme. If it's only possible by extensive coding, then that's of course a valid result.

Comment: One way to do rotation using mouse movement would be thumbs in adorners. Like control resize and move works in the designers.

Comment: I have finally found the time to read up on the Thumb control. With respect to my requirements it's a little limited (only left mouse button induces drag; no modifier state sequences, see my question), but I think it's not a big deal to modify it to suit my needs.

Comment: I have a usercontrol inside a thumb. I just do drag using the thumb. All that other stuff you see there is in the usercontrol.